# What piece of veal should I ask a butcher/meat shop in the US if I want to do stew dishes like "blanquette de veau" or "veau marengo"?

Tags: cut-of-meat, butchering, veal

Ideally, I should be using ["tendron"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendron) which I think is equivalent to flank steak for a veal. But flank steak is "bavette" for beef, so maybe it is a different name. I think I could also use jarret, which is for the pork called ham hock I believe. Do I have any chance of finding these pieces? Do they have a proper name in US english?

Any other piece suggestions for veal-based stew dishes?

Comment: IIRC, when chef-daughter was practicing for a practical day in which they would do blanquette de veau, the ingredient list called for "veal shoulder" which Canadian butchers understood and were able to provide.

Answer (score 2):

Veal and beef cuts are completely different, the terminology is not the same at all. With veal the tendron is part of the breast, which includes the foreleg and the front of what would be considered the flank on a full-sized animal, in other words the part that does the most work. The tendron cut includes the lower-front part of the ribs. As for what to ask a US butcher for I'm not sure, I'd ask for veal foreribs and hope that they get what I'm after.

Here are some [definitions](http://www.lexic.us/definition-of/tendrons) that may help.

Comment: This is a good description. A US butcher should know what veal breast is, and if you're doing a special order anyways, you can describe what bits you want. Even if they're starting from primals or smaller pieces, they should be able to throw the right pieces into a box.

Answer (score 0):

For any stew - I prefer the shank or "ossobuco."  A quick lookup of the recipes that you mentioned discuss not having the bone but for most stews I like throwing in large hunks of shank and letting it fall off the bone later.